How LLM X100 Context window?
A declared context window for chatGPT-3 generation models is 16k tokens, 4k for turbo. Same for Llama 2: 4k tokens. In the next generation context window increased in 100 times! Reaches 128k, 200k and even 500k (Claude enterprise) tokes. What happen? Is there a new model architecture which allows such improvement?
Simple increase of number of parameters could benefit context window size, but the computation of wider window is quadratic, so training process must be way too longer.
